# Add UITableView to iOS 8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am trying to add an `UITableView` to a custom keyboard in iOS8. Since the keyboard has no interface file like a storyboard, I need to add the `UITableView` programatically, but it won't appear.
In `viewDidLoad` I am doing this:

```
self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Then I implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am doing this:

```
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CopyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    if let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CopyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell {
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Hello World"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }else{
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CopyCell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Hello World"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    return cell
```

I don´t know if I missed some important detail, but the table view won´t appear in the custom keyboard, I added the colors of the background and the cells to indicate it.

Comment: Did you add the tableView() to a view inside your keyboard. For example. parentView.addSubView(tableView)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by:

1) adding a tableview to a XIB file

2) assigning the XIB's File's owner class to the KeyboardViewController

3) hooking up the delegate and datasource to File's Owner

4) creating an outlet for a tableview in your KeyboardViewController.m and hooking that up in the XIB file

From there you have to make sure to register a class for the tableView's cell:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableView class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

You will also want to make sure to include this init method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"Keyboard" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}
```

From there you implement the table's delegate methods in the KeyboardViewController as normal and you will see the changes. Feel free to reach out if you need any help as I was working kind of extensively with this the last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView with XIB only you can not add it programatically.